# Three.js Load texture without MTLLoader

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to make a project with Three.js and i have some questions.

I want to add a texture in a Obj file without using MTLLoader.

So i'm doing the follow code:

#

```
var loader  = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
var textureBody = new THREE.Texture();
loader.load( 'obj/t1.jpg', function ( image ) {
  textureBody.image = image;
  textureBody.needsUpdate = true;
});

var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.load( 'obj/salto.obj', function ( object ) {
       object.traverse( function ( child )
       {
          if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
          {
            meshes.push(child);
          }
      });
      var head = meshes[0];
      head.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: textureBody, specular: 0xfceed2, shininess: 0}); 
      head.position.y = -18;
      head.position.x = 5;

      scene.add(head);
  }, onProgress, onError );
```

#

The problem is that the texture in the object don't fit as it should

[image: Image of the sample]

as you can see in the heels i have to mush distortion in the texture.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like a UV issue and not a texture loading issue. I suppose that MTL loader adjusts UVs if your results are different with and without it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Then i guess results should look identical. There's a bit of lack in terms of details in the question with regards to what's expected and how actual result differs from that.